# PPTP and windows 7 809 error

Tags: vpn, linux-networking, pptp, pptpd

I want to connect from home to my router(linux mashine) at work.

i have installed pptpd.
i have added following fw rules:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p gre -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp --dport 1723 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -p gre -j ACCEPT
```

I have checked if my router is listening on 1723 using:

```
netstat -lptu
```

I can ping it.
I have disabled windows firewall
I have forwarded all traffic on my home router.

everything seems to work fine and i still receive 809 error - server doesnt response ???? why ?? Anyone had similar problem ?

Comment: Friends don't let friends use PPTP. Just use OpenVPN. You'll have a better day if you do so.

Comment: i know it is bad idea to use pptp and i will use openvpn for sure but i need to find an answer or i will not fall asleep.

Comment: I think you may be putting too much stock into technology's role in your life. If you know you're not going to use PPTP, then why even bother with this? Just cut your losses and start working on OpenVPN.

Comment: I just don't like when i can't do something and i dont know why.

Comment: Besides ping, have you tried a network monitor like [**Wireshark**](http://www.wireshark.org/)?

Answer (score 1):

The problem may simply be that the GRE packets are not getting through.

To resolve this issue, make sure the network router/firewall permits GRE protocol 47 (You will want to find and enable a "PPTP passthrough" feature on your router that knows how to handle the GRE packets). In fact both port 1723 and GRE protocol shoyld be opened/enabled to establish VPN connectivity by using PPTP. If you are using Arno's IPTables Firewall, enable the plugin for PPTP then.

Hope it could solve the problem.